# Converting Plain texts to Links in php

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my question .
Requirement is, I've to convert the plain text into links.

> 1. I've to select any file to upload and store it in to the database (For multiple docs I'm separating with * and storing it in database). (DONE)
> 2. Along with this I'm storing the docs into local directory also. (DONE)
> 3. But when I am showing the docs to the user, it will display like xxxx.docx  . Instead of this I want http://localhost:81/foldername/xxxx.docx as a link. So that the User can click on this. (I want help in this)

Hope the question is clear.

Comment: I want code in this.

Comment: Regex is the solution

Comment: if these links are being retrieved from the db, you could try like this: echo "<a href='".$row['link']."'>$row['link']</a>";

Comment: So what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use like this

```
echo "http://www.".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/yourfolder/".$your file;
```

Comment: It will display 0 if I append this

Comment: why it will display 0??

Comment: or you can save the server url in $config and append this with file

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing link this.

```
   while($pfet=mysql_fetch_assoc($pay1))  
              {

               $next=$pfet['f_name']; //display full path
                $next1 = basename($next);  // display only file name
               $aid=$pfet['id'];
               echo '<a class="astex" href="'.$next.'"  download><p style="margin-left:2cm;">'.$next.'</a>';
              }
```